# Proof that 2, 4, 6, 8, ... divided by 2...

Tags: number-theory

Consider the sequence of numbers: 2, 4, 6, 8, ...

I need a proof which shows that every number in this sequence of numbers when divided by 2, yields a smaller number than it.

One way is to test every number individually:
2/2=1<2, 4/2=2<4, ...

but in this case we would need an infinite number of proofs, right?

Another way is to see the pattern in this sequence of numbers. And we could say that the pattern is 2n, n=1,2,3,...
So:
2n/2=n<2n
And we offered a simple proof.

Now my question.
But how do I know that the pattern is correct? I've used the pattern to prove something, but how do I know that the pattern is itself correct? 
Do I just say that it is correct because it looks obvious that it is correct?

Or maybe my proof is not correct and I would like to see a correct proof.

Comment: `Consider the sequence of numbers: 2, 4, 6, 8, ...` That defines a sequence of $4$ numbers, no more no less. If you want to extend it beyond that, you must provide a definition for the general $n^{th}$ term. The proof will then depend on what definition you provide.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I provide the pattern after all

Comment: Well, it depends on how the basic laws of arithmetic were derived.  You have n = 2; n > 1.  Does it follow m> 0; m/n < m whenever n > 1?  It really depends on your axioms.

Comment: By definition your sequence is $2*1, 2*2, 2*3....$ so each term is $2m$ if you divide that in half you get $m$.  Can you prove that $2m > m$ for all $m$?

Comment: Use the axioms of an ordered field. First check that $2>1$ cause $2=1+1>1$. Now check that $0<2^{-1}<1$ cause $2\cdot2^{-1}=1$. This implies that $n\cdot 0< n\cdot 2^{-1}<n\cdot 1$ for all positive $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a basic axiom of arithmetic is that if $n > 0$ and $a > b$ then $na > nb$.  And we know $2 > 1$[@]. So for any $m > 0$ we have $2m > m$

And we know $2m \frac 12 = m$ and $m < 2m$ so $2m \frac 12 < 2m$.

Of course, this depends *entirely* one what rules and axioms you used to derive and define the rules of arithmetic.  [For example, do you know that if $n > 0$ and $a > b$ then $na > nb$.  So you know that $2 > 1$?  Do you know $2m \frac 12 =m$.  I actually do not not what you are, or are not, expected to know, derive, or take on faith.  It depends *entirely* on your class and your textbook.  And they *do* differ.]

[@] Or do we?